# Launch using dedicated graphics card disappeared after AMD driver updates Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, 64-bit, radeon, amd-graphics

I'm new here and I'm also new to using Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 with GNOME 3.34.2, I have switcheroo control updated to the latest version and also the most recent AMD drivers.

Yesterday I updated my drivers for my GPU because I had problems starting with the "launch with dedicated graphics card" because it wasn't actually using my dedicated graphics card. I updated the drivers and had some problems with broken packages and I had to follow some guides in here.

After finally installing the drivers, I restarted the PC and now the "launch with dedicated graphics card" disappeared.

Also, when I check using the command `sudo lshw -C video` my discrete graphics card results UNCLAIMED (don't know what it means):

```
   *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: da
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0800000-f0ffffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:f0500000-f053ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f0400000-f043ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0440000-f045ffff
```

Here are my specs:

```
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: AMD A9-9420 RADEON R5 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G 
  bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Excavator L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm 
  bogomips: 11977 
  Speed: 3480 MHz min/max: 1400/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2269 2: 2248 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
  driver: amdgpu v: kernel bus ID: 00:01.0 
  Device-2: AMD Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / 
  Radeon 520 Mobile] 
  vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: N/A resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD STONEY (DRM 3.33.0 5.3.0-46-generic LLVM 9.0.1) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 20.1.0-devel (git-8398183 2020-04-20 eoan-oibaf-ppa) 
  direct render: Yes
```

This PC is a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed amdgpu (and it looks like you have) then the radeon driver will have been disabled. You need the radeon driver for older cards - I have a Radeon HD5000 and a Radeon R9 290X. I was able to get the 290X running with amdgpu but the HD5000 stopped working. So I re-enabled the radeon driver for the old card and continued to use the new amdgpu driver for the new card.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235587/radeon-rx-5500-xt-unclaimed/1251879#1251879) for more details.

Comment: Thank you but a kind redditor user helped me out. He spent 4/5 hours helping me out. Strangely, my Radeon gpu got blacklisted when I did the update. We couldn't figure it out why but we fixed it

Comment: No problem - glad you got it sorted. It's the radeon driver that's blacklisted and it's blacklisted because the newer amdgpu drivers (also for Radeon cards) are installed. The amdgpu installation wrongly assumes that all of your graphics cards will work with amdgpu, which was not true for both of us.