# Radeon RX 5500 XT UNCLAIMED

Tags: 18.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have a dual boot PC running Windows 10 and Ububtu 18.04.4, with 5.3.0-51-generic kernel. With windows the graphic card work perfectly, on Linux I'm experimenting a lot of trouble. I tried to instal amdgpu and the installation goes well with the last version of the driver (20.10), but after reboot, the screen was flickering so fast that the only login was a hard operation. Now I tried to follow the second point of [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) but it also has no effect. At least neither negative effect.
The output of my `sudo lshw -C video` is:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcc00000-fcc7ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

The information screen say i'm using `llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 256 bits)`[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOBIl.png).
So I would like to use the proper driver, can anyone help me?

**EDIT**
I think I miss the kernel modules of amdgpu, `lsmod |grep amdgpu` give no result and in my `lspci` output the `Kernel modules` voice doesn't exist

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 7340 (rev c5)
    Subsystem: Sapphire Technology Limited Device e421
0a:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device ab38
    Subsystem: Sapphire Technology Limited Device e421
```

Also `$ sudo lshw -c display | grep driver` doesn't give any output.
`glxinfo`, instead, tell me that direct rendering is Ok

```
$ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 256 bits)
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_image, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, 
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS solved it. It's the first release that includes the drivers out-of-the-box AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you Mikel for your reply, I tried to upgrade to 20.04 and the result was flickering monitor, so maybe I'll wait for the 20.04.03 and the direct distro-upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

if you've installed amdgpu on Ubuntu 18.04.4 then the radeon driver will have been disabled. You need the radeon driver for older cards - I have a Radeon HD5000 and a Radeon R9 290X. I was able to get the 290X running with amdgpu but the HD5000 stopped working.

Re-enabling the radeon driver and forcing the HD5000 to use it made both displays work again!

Here's what you need to do:

1. Delete the blacklist file for radeon (Store a copy of this first)

   sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf ~

   sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf
2. Create an Xorg config file

   sudo vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf

This should contain details of each of your video cards and which drivers you would like to use for them.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier             "Screen0"
    Driver                 "amdgpu"
    VendorName             "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
    BusID                  "PCI:X:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier             "Screen1"
    Driver                 "radeon"
    VendorName             "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
    BusID                  "PCI:X:0:0"
EndSection
```

You can get the value for BusID (PCI:X:0:0) from the following command:

```
lspci | grep VGA

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii XT / Grenada XT [Radeon R9 290X/390X]
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
```

The first card is on bus 1 and the value for xorg would be PCI:1:0:0. The second card is on bus 5 and the value in the xorg file would be PCI:5:0:0.

Hope this helps someone.